# Creating simple TOC - overwhelming problems in Article Class

Tags: table-of-contents

I am trying to create my Table of Contents for few days now, but despite few good attempts, it does not land on the final shape I am looking for. Simply, I want:

```
Contents:

Acknowledgement                      ii
Copyright                            ii
Abstract and Table of Contents       iii

1 Introduction 
2 Alexander Polynomials 
3. ..
4. ...
```

But the problem is, I am in Article Class, and cannot use Book Class.
Also, the First THREE SECTIONS, are NOT sections! I just want the TOC to divert to those pages when clicked on it.

I tried different techniques from web by adding the command

```
\makeatletter

\newif\if@mainmatter \@mainmattertrue

\newcommand\frontmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{roman}}
\newcommand\mainmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmattertrue
  \pagenumbering{arabic}}
\makeatother
```

but I have managed to create what I want, but the links jump on the first page as follows:

```
\frontmatter 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgement}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Copyright}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract and Table of Contents}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage


\mainmatter 
\section{Introduction}

 \pagenumbering{arabic}
```

In the table of content, in front of the first three section, it all shows (i). How can I divert a link in TOC to the desired page I wish?

If anyone can help me sort this out, I really appreciate their time and energy.

HERE IS ALL MY CODE:

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    
    \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{framed}
    \usepackage{todonotes}
    \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
    \usepackage{mathrsfs}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{ {./Images/} }
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks=true,
        linkcolor=blue,
        filecolor=magenta,      
        urlcolor=blue,
        }
    
    \urlstyle{same}
    
    
    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.3}
    
    \makeatletter
    
    \newif\if@mainmatter \@mainmattertrue
    
    \newcommand\frontmatter{%
        \cleardoublepage
      \@mainmatterfalse
      \pagenumbering{roman}}
    \newcommand\mainmatter{%
        \cleardoublepage
      \@mainmattertrue
      \pagenumbering{arabic}}
    \makeatother
    
    
    
    \title{Title}
    \author{Author}
    \date{August 2021}
    
    
    
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    
    

    
    
    \pagebreak
    
  Thanks for contributing an answer to TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange!

Please be sure to answer the question. Provide details and share your research!
But avoid …

Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers.
Making statements based on opinion; back them up with references or personal experience.
To learn more, see our tips on writing great answers. \\ \\
    
    \noindent \textbf{{\Large Author's contact details:}} \\
Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers.
Making statements based on opinion; back them up with references or personal experience.
To learn more, see our tips on writing great answers.
    
    
    
    
    \noindent \textbf{{\Large Acknowledgement:}} \\
Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers.
Making statements based on opinion; back them up with references or personal experience.
To learn more, see our tips on writing great answers.
    
    
    \noindent \textbf{{\Large Copyright:}}

Asking for help, clarification, or responding to other answers.
Making statements based on opinion; back them up with references or personal experience.
To learn more, see our tips on writing great answers.
    
    \begin{abstract}
    hjgjhg jhgjhg
    \end{abstract}
    
    \frontmatter 
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgement}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Copyright}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract and Table of Contents}
    
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    
    
    \mainmatter 
    \section{Introduction}
    
     \pagenumbering{arabic}
    
    
    
    
    
    \end{document}
```

Here is an example of what I am looking for:
[image]

Comment: In your example code snippet, the "sections" `Acknowledgement`, `Copyright` and `Abstract and Table of Contents` are all blank, and therefore all point to the page on which they're created, which is the first page. Perhaps you can provide a complete, minimal working example/MWE that replicates the current behaviour - something we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see exactly what you're seeing. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`, rather than code snippets you've currently provided. Can you provide us with an MWE?

Comment: If you mean hyperref links,  then you probably should add \phantomsection which would create the anchor.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./Images/} }
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue,
    }

\urlstyle{same}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}


\makeatletter

\newif\if@mainmatter \@mainmattertrue

\newcommand\frontmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{roman}}
\newcommand\mainmatter{%
    \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmattertrue
  \pagenumbering{arabic}}
\makeatother


\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\phantomsection
\section{Acknowledgement}


\phantomsection
\section{Copyright}


\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract and Table of Contents}


\mainmatter
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\section{Introduction}


\section{Alexander Polynomial $\triangle (t)$}
\subsection{History and overview}


\section{Conway Polynomial $\nabla (z)$}
\subsection{History and overview}


\section{Jones Polynomial $V(q)$}
\subsection{History and overview}


\section{HOMFLY Polynomial $H(a,z)$}
\subsection{History and overview}


\section{Vassiliev Invariant}
\subsection{History and overview}


\section{Conclusion}

\section{References}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If this is an update to your original question, you should edit it to be in the question.  If this is an answer to your original question, it would be helpful to say how you solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't need to fight with this faked `\frontmatter/\mainmatter`and `secnumdepth` switching which are definitely overkill. The *standard* solution is

1. `\section*{...}` to suppress the numbering of the 3 first sections
2. `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{...}` to include the starred section in the `toc`, as you did.
3. `\phantomsection` to get an hyperlink, as suggested in @ulrike comment.
4. If you want, manually insert
   `\pagenumbering{roman}` and `\pagenumbering{arabic}` at suitable places, as you did.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{August 2021}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue}
\begin{document}
  \pagenumbering{roman}
\maketitle
\section*{Acknowledgements}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgements}
  \phantomsection
   A text...
\section*{Copyright}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Copyright}
  \phantomsection
  An other text...
\section*{Abstract and Table of Contents}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract and Table of Contents}
  \phantomsection
  Some text...
\tableofcontents
% Here starts the main matter
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Introduction}
   More text...

\end{document}
```

Note: The position of `\addcontentsline` and `\phantomsection`  with respect to the corresponding element (before or after) may vary depending on the context.